# Flutter how can i print just a value from an array

Tags: flutter

Flutter i need to print a simple data but dont know what is an issue its showing null but it have a value.

my code

```
  var url =
        'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/drive_api/location.php?imei=358480081983837';
    print(url);
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'token': 'c66026133e80d4960f0a5b7d418a4d08'
      },
    );
    var data = json.decode(res.body);
      print(data);

    if (data['status'].toString() == "success") {
      print(data['location']);
    }
```

if i run api in postman it looks like this

```
 {
    "origin": {
        "id": "b733bc40-aafe-421d-8fed-4067bcdb5afc",
        "name": "358480081983837"
    },
    "date": "2020-12-22T10:10:40.000Z",
    "received": "2020-12-22T10:11:39.000Z",
    "active": false,
    "linked": [
        {
            "id": "73f0516a-76ff-4abb-bf78-7b2493b6c94a",
            "name": "APL-Muhammad Saleem Ahmed",
            "type": "asset"
        }
    ],
    "zones": [
        {
            "id": "8ea7dd50-b00d-4880-aaf2-3f924c1ae503",
            "name": "Pakistan",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "bd90ec5b-2da8-4022-bca0-7a9e7603c2fc",
            "name": "Karachi",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "4087d332-5277-48bc-a23e-400d2c15ea31",
            "name": "Sindh",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "4ca687c6-9d25-47b5-8f2f-9117dab39cea",
            "name": "Sindh Province",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "3c73b284-498d-4661-989b-ee6401708c85",
            "name": " Karachi",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "b5c0d124-c1ba-495d-9c62-6bc766639731",
            "name": "International Boundary",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "a0f7186a-42e5-4eec-b529-a933a5cdb0e1",
            "name": "Pakistan",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "a9a4ec02-f0a0-40c7-8a00-c1cea582a9ca",
            "name": "Sindh",
            "type": "keepin"
        },
        {
            "id": "e57df14d-191e-4c31-bd3c-78fa1ac2e2d7",
            "name": "Karachi",
            "type": "keepin"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [],
    "state": {},
    "spd": null,
    "location": {
        "lon": 67.036763,
        "lat": 24.827595,
        "speed": 0,
        "altitude": 25,
        "heading": 1,
        "accuracy": 13,
        "age": 0,
        "gc": {
            "rd": "Khayaban-e-Rumi",
            "sb": "Clifton Block 9",
            "tw": "Clifton",
            "ct": "Pakistan"
        },
        "address": "Khayaban-e-Rumi, Clifton Block 9, Clifton, Pakistan"
    },
    "telemetry": {
        "priority": 0,
        "eventId": 0,
        "ignition": 0,
        "moving": 0,
        "motion_end": 1,
        "gsm_signal": 3,
        "digital_01": 0,
        "output_01": 0,
        "power_voltage": 12.73,
        "gps_speed": 0,
        "gsm_cell": 10283,
        "gsm_lac": 727,
        "battery_voltage": 3.996,
        "battery_current": 0,
        "analog_01": 173,
        "fuel_rate": 18.95,
        "x": -0.02,
        "eco_score": 10,
        "gsm_code": 41004,
        "odo_diff": 0,
        "odometer": 20403.945,
        "fuel_counter": 3839.767,
        "movement": 0,
        "hours_00_counter": 1177.310307,
        "idle_counter": 0
    },
    "counters": {
        "odometer": 20403.945,
        "hours": 1177.310307
    },
    "io": {
        "output_01": {
            "type": "output",
            "input": "output_01",
            "name": "Immobilizer",
            "value": 0,
            "text": "Off",
            "unit": ""
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "dsid": "deviceserver2@b314b24a22c6",
        "wshost": "dws.eu1.kt1.io",
        "wsport": 80,
        "ecsid": "69ebf0b0b87645318ec79d2cc883a5f3",
        "tpsq": 0
    },
    "object": {
        "id": "73f0516a-76ff-4abb-bf78-7b2493b6c94a",
        "name": "APL-Muhammad Saleem Ahmed",
        "type": "asset"
    },
    "lastMovement": "2020-12-22T04:20:08.000Z"
}
```

i just want to print lon and lat values. but dont know why in flutter its showing null.

[image]

you can see my console its showing value in lon but its cut dont know why. I am stuck on this point and i know its very basic in flutter. But can any one please help how can i print just a value ?

i already try multiple ways like

```
print(data['location']['lon']);
```

but its showing null

Comment: What `print(data);` is showing is not similar to the json your posted here. The output in your console differ to the actual json you posted

Comment: @dm_tr too longs thats why i have edited and add whole json now

Comment: Firstly looking at the json it doesn't look like there is a 'status' key, so I am not sure what is happening with that if statement. 
Regardless, if you want to access 'lon' which is nested inside the location json object. 
the following may be useful.

`var location = data['location'] as Map;
print(location['lon']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing my own investigation, I found that the actual structure of your data is

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "origin": {
      // ...
    },
    "date": "2020-12-22T12:49:55.000Z",
    "location": {
      "lon": 67.036763,
      "lat": 24.827595,
      // ...
    },
  }
}
```

So to access the location longitude you have to do

```
print(data["data"]["location"]["lon"]);
```

Comment: Thanks. now i am feeling like a bot xD

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
final locationMap = Map<String,dynamic>.from(data['location']);
print(locationMap['lon']);
```